# iOS: Iterating Through Scores & Adding Them Up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, iteration, game-center

I'm using the following method to retrieve the top 100 scores from one of my gamecenter leaderboards. Everything is working, correctly, except that as I retrieve a score, I'd like to add them up, so that once it is done, I have 1 total score.

How could I fix it?

```
- (void) retrieveTop100Scores {

GKLeaderboard *leaderboard1 = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

leaderboard1.identifier = [Team currentTeam];
leaderboard1.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
leaderboard1.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
leaderboard1.range = NSMakeRange(1, 100);

[leaderboard1 loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    if (scores != nil) {

        for (GKScore *score in scores) {

            NSLog(@"%lld", score.value);
            //Add them all up here?
        }
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: You need some sort of "total" variable. Simply add each score to the total.

Comment: Thank's rmaddy! Just one issue with that, I get a missing block error when doing something like, int totalScore = totalScore + score.value;

Comment: NOTE: I declare my totalScore variable and set it to 0 at the beginning of the method.

Comment: You need to declare the variable outside of the loop.

Comment: Sounds like you get an error because you declared totalScore outside of the block (loadScoresWithCompletionHandler). You will need __block modifier to be able to modify variable inside the block like this: __block NSInteger totalScore;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a variable outside of the loop, and in each iteration, `var+=score.value`. Therefore after the iteration, the variable you build will contain the total score.

Comment: Thanks TonyD! Along with your answer, and rmaddy & Bird's comments I was able to do this in a very clean and effiecent manner!